# ESP8266 html page code integrated into .ino file

Tags: html, c, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm using an ESP8266 and this is the HTML part of the program. I copy and pasted from the depths of the internet and want to change the HTML page of the file. In what format can I add html code? Thanks! (I was trying to put a text-input field in but I want to put many HTML elements in later).

```
const String HtmlHtml = "<html><head>" 
"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" /></head>";`
const String HtmlHtmlClose = "</html>";
const String HtmlTitle = "<h1>Arduino-er: ESP8266 AP WebServer exercise</h1><br/>\n";
const String HtmlLedStateLow = "<big>LED is now <b>ON</b></big><br/>\n";
const String HtmlLedStateHigh = "<big>LED is now <b>OFF</b></big><br/>\n";
const String HtmlButtons = 
"<a href=\"LEDOn\"><button style=\"display: block; width: 100%;\">ON</button></a><br/>" 
"<a href=\"LEDOff\"><button style=\"display: block; width: 100%;\">OFF</button></a><br/>";
```

Comment: you want to be writing all those strings to the target file.   `<html>` is not a valid first line in a HTML web page.  The `<html>` block ends at the bottom of the web page, not 'usually' immediately after the end of the `<head>` block.  There are a number of other things that are needed in the `<head>` block besides what is posted.  The posted code is missing the `<body>` block, which is where those <a...> references should be located.  Suggest writing the desired HTML page, then insert all the needed statements to save it to a file -or- display it in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you later have part where you combine your variables and make one big that you use to dispalay html. You can do something like this.

-Open your editor and copy/paste code from your post

-Edit it as you want

-Delete variables in code that you posted and replace with one, example

```
  const String wholePage = "INSERT YOUR HTML";
```

-And than on line where you added variables before just use your new where is whole HTML code

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thank you this makes waaaayyy more sense now! is there a way i can take the information entered into a <form> text field in the html and save it to eeprom and bring it up on the webpage by entering a password into the same text field?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can stream an HTML file from SPIFFS. Here is an [example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser/FSBrowser.ino) :

You need to get **streamFile()** function as denoted below :

```
  String contentType = "text/html";
  if(SPIFFS.exists(path)){
    File file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r");
    size_t sent = server.streamFile(file, contentType);
    file.close();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: can i save information entered on in a <form> to eeprom and have some way of viewing it later

Comment: This example demonstrates the file serving way, it will help you to have readable html files. If you want to save the request which is incoming to your webserver via this page, of course you can save it but in another file. To do it you can follow the [guide](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.md).

Comment: is there a way i can use       SPIFFS.open(path, mode)     in the place of responseHTML in this code snippit:                                                                                                                           dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  // replay to all requests with same HTML
  webServer.onNotFound([]() {
    webServer.send(200, "text/html", responseHTML);
  });
  webServer.begin();
}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider cleaning it up to use an unescaped multi-line syntax:

```
void handleAbout() {
    const char* message = R"foo(
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
     <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
    </head><body class=container>
    <h1>testing</h1>
    <main>
     <h3>Status</h3>
      <ul>
      <li>Mode: <b>[[MODE]]</b>
       <li><a href=/reset >reboot device</a>
      </ul>
    </main>
    </body>
    </html>
    )foo";

    String message2= String(message);
    // templating replaces string-concat functionality:
    message2.replace("[[MODE]]", String(inputMode));
    // prove it's a usable String to the esp:
    server.send(200, "text/html", message2);
} // end about section handler
```

You can also use any online text-to-json encoder to make C-friendly escaped String literals from arbitrary text. ex: [my slim's "JSON.stringify"](http://danml.com/slim/) engine transform...